# Diferencia threads.p y windows.h

Tags: c++

Buscando por internet he visto en muchos tutoriales que se usa la librería threads.h para crear hilos en windows, pero en otros usan directamente la cabecera windows.h. ¿Cual de las dos debería usar para crear un hilo? Por lo que he visto, creo que me daria "menos dolor de cabeza" la libreria threads.h..

Comment: Posible duplicado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79087/sockets-en-windows-con-c

Answer (score 3):

La librería `threads` (sin extensión) se encuentra disponible desde el estándar C++11 (allá por el 2011). Al formar parte del estándar el código fuente será portable entre sistemas.

Windows dispone de su propia API para la gestión de procesos. La ventaja de usar esta librería es que pueden estar disponibles posibilidades que no sean accesibles desde la librería estándar... la contrapartida es que el código fuente no será portable a, por ejemplo, sistemas Linux.

Comment: Me refiero a la libreria windows.h para crear hilos, no para los sockets

Comment: cierto... no se por qué he empezado hablando de threads y me he pasado a sockets... lo arreglo en seguida... confusión rara la mia

Comment: @Jogofus ya está, lamento la confusión

Comment: Utilizando la libreria threads sería portable para sistemas Linux? He estado viendo que para Unix se usa la libreria para POSIX pthread. Habría algun inconveniente usar la primera en lugar de la especifica para POSIX?

Comment: @Jogofus si usas el estándar el codigo sera portable... por algo es un estándar.. el unico requisito es utilizar un compilador compatible con el estándar.  En este caso c++11 o superior